# How do i create a program that lets the user enter a sentence then put that sentence into a list and converts each word for the position of the word

Tags: python-3.4

```
sentence  = []
sentence = input("Please enter a sentence")                        #asks the user to enter a sentence
for i in range(10):                                                #number of words to be searched for
    search = input("please enter a word to be searched for: ")     #asks for a word to be searched for
    letters = sentence.split(' ')#splits the sentence
    correct = False
    for (i, letters) in enumerate(letters):
        if (letters == search):
            print ("your word has been found in position(s): ")    #prints the position of the words
            print (i)
            works = True #the word has been found
            if not True :
                   print("Sorry this word is not in the sentence ")#prints the word cannot be found**
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`if not True :` is always `False` and you need to "outdent" it, as it is using the wrong spacing, so does the print statement following.

so `if not True :` will never do the following:

`print("Sorry this word is not in the sentence ")`

you might want to change that to something like `if not works:` but you do not define `works = False` anywhere, but you do define `correct = False` so maybe you are mixing up the names of variables here.

So your code should look something like this:

```
sentence  = []
sentence = input("Please enter a sentence")                        #asks the user to enter a sentence
for i in range(10):                                                #number of words to be searched for
    search = input("please enter a word to be searched for: ")     #asks for a word to be searched for
    letters = sentence.split(' ')#splits the sentence
    correct = False
    for (i, letters) in enumerate(letters):
        if (letters == search):
            print ("your word has been found in position(s): ")    #prints the position of the words
            print (i)
            correct = True #the word has been found
    if not correct :
        print("Sorry this word is not in the sentence ")#prints the word cannot be found**
```

This should work, although it might require further clean up, example: why are you doing this `sentence  = []` if you take a string as input in the next line. Click here for [Code Reviews](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

HTH.